# Breaking lease early

Tags: united-states, real-estate-leasing

I went to my leasing office to see if I can put my 30 days notice in. They told me that I had to pay 2 months rent in order to move out and break my lease. They then stated that it's in my lease. When reviewing my lease, it says no such thing. It says I have to give a written 30 days notice, so I went back the next day and explained this. The staff was rude. I never spoke with the leasing manager; they claim she was out of state, then they said it's the law that I pay them two months rent even though my lease says no such thing. What should I do? July is almost over.

Comment: If the contract really doesn't say that, you do what the contract says and if they won't hold up their end, you sue them. But I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.

Comment: I've been there for 3 1/2 yrs but went i moved in they weren't my managers they original manager got brought out so they don't even know how my apartment looked before I moved in

Comment: did you sign any newer leases since the one you signed 3.5 years ago?

Comment: Real estate law is at the state and local level, please specify the state.

Comment: How long was your lease?  Is this residential or commercial?  What is the jurisdiction?

Comment: Have you renewed the lease since you first moved in (which more-or-less equals signing a new lease) or has your original lease 'expired' and 'rolled over' into a month-to-month arrangement?

Answer (score 6):

You may want to have someone else review the lease who is not as emotionally involved.  Two months rent is pretty normal for breaking a lease early.

You could inform them of your move out date, and then not pay.

In turn, the leasing company will probably put derogatory marks on your credit report and keep your deposit.  It is fairly common, in these hostile situations for leasing companies to claim all kinds of damage to the apartment. This is an effort to collect above and beyond your deposit.

Then you can sue them.  This might be in small claims court, or your jurisdiction may have a special hearing board to dispute rental disagreements.  Proof is everything.  If your lease has no such clause, and you documented that you left the rental in good order, you will win.  It might take a year or two, but you should get all your money back and have the derogatory remark removed from your credit.

Comment: Ima still look into it but they are a bad company it took them 2 mths to fix my sink and they still haven't fix my patio screen

Comment: @theJohnsonsistersJohn Well if it comes to it, that could also be part of your complaint that they failed to uphold their end of the lease by not providing timely repairs.  What state are you in?